# How can I get Outlook 2013 to show the time a sender sent an email rather than the time it was received?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2013

How can I have Outlook 2013 to show the time a sender sent an email rather than the time it was received?

Answer (score 0):

You can customize columns in the mail view. Right-click the message list header, select **View Settings...** and click the **Columns...** button. Now you can select **Sent** from Frequently-used fields and click the **Add->** button to display this date in the list of messages.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback thims. I tried adding all the columns I could find like Sent and Created, but they are just a repeat of the Received time. I know our connection is not that fast. I have seen emails take as long as 10 min with large attachments.

Comment: Sorry, no other date fields available. It looks like there is a problem on either your server or sender's client/server (that doesn't append correct Date: header to messages).